# Corollary of Hahn-Banach

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$  be a normed space on $\mathbb{R}$ . Given a particular $x_0\in X$, there exists $f\in X'$ such that $\|f\|=1 $ and $f(x_0)=\|x_0\|$

I'm interesting  about the uniqueness of $f$?

On wiki  https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espace_strictement_convexe , I found: We call the dual conjugate element of $x_0$ any element f of the topological dual E 'of E satisfying:$\|f\|=1 $ and $f(x_0)=\|x_0\|$

The existence of such f is ensured by the Hahn-Banach theorem (thus by means of Zorn's lemma).
We say that E is a smooth space https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espace_lisse if every vector of E has a unique dual conjugated element

we give  that a strictely convex space is smooth. 
My question if X be not lisse, can you give  two f  satisfying  $\|f\|=1 $ and $f(x_0)=\|x_0\|$

Comment: We can't prove uniqueness, unless $X$ is one dimensional..

Comment: What happens when $x_0=0$?

Comment: Example.  Use the $l^\infty$ norm in two dimensions.  In case $\|x_0\| = 1$, your norming functional $f$ corresponds to a line passing through the point $x_0$ and everewhere outside or on the boundary of the unit ball.  If $x_0$ is at  a corner of your ball, there are multiple lines like that.  To get uniqueness, you can require that the norm "have no corners".  But what does that mean technically?

Comment: i have edited my question because i found some result on wiki (french)

Answer (score 2):

What does the Hahn-Banach theorem guarantee in terms of uniqueness?

What exactly do we know about the functional $f$? The answer is "very little". We know the value it takes at $x_0$, and hence on the linear subspace spanned by $x_0$. The next natural question "what are possible candidates for the kernel of $f$?" There are probably a lot of these! Any closed linear subspace of codimension one of $X$ that does not contain $x_0$ is possible. So what does this say about the uniqueness of $f$?

Comment: Not every closed linear subspace not containing $x_0$ can *be* the kernel, but each such is *contained in* a kernel of some homomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

In  general $f$ is far from unique. But for example it's unique if $E$ is a Hilbert space.

Comment: thank's for all